# How to set an assignment and then comparison?

Tags: python-3.x

I keep getting the error "test3 is not defined" for the following code:

```
def pointsToPass(test1, test2, target):
  test3 == (3 * target) - test1 - test2
  if test3 < 100:
    return test3
  else:
    return 'Sorry - not possible'`
```

I can't figure out what the issue is, can anyone help?

Comment: `==` is not an assignment.

Comment: @usr2564301 Thank you! That solved the problem for situations where test3 < 100. But when test3 > 100, the program still doesn't display 'Sorry - not possible' like I want it to. Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: I fixed the problem now, thanks for the help

Comment: What values are you calling this function with? (It's important enough to [edit] this in your question.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use one '=' and not '==' on the second line.

```
test3 = (3 * target) - test1 - test2
```

I am guessing it was a typo, but in case it wasn't :

You should know that when using '==' you are actually comparing and therefor returning a Boolean statement.

Comment: That solved the problem for situations where test3 < 100. But when test3 > 100, the program still doesn't display 'Sorry - not possible' like I want it to. Do you know what could be causing that?

Comment: @Sam Thats doesnt sound right, try printing the value of test3 to verify it really is larger then 100 in those cases.

Comment: I fixed it now nvm. I had to change > to >=. Thank you for the help

Comment: @Sam Best of luck :)